# Bootstrap 3 DateTimepicker Display TimePicker first

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I'm working with the datetimepicker found here:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Maybe the answer is right in front of me, but I can't find it. How do you default to showing the edit time screen first? I'm creating a time keeping app, and I'd rarely change the date, but usually change the time.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, its a little hackey but based on the response here:

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/840

i added

`$(".datetimepicker").on 'dp.show', () ->
      $(document).find('.picker-switch a[data-action="togglePicker"]').click()`

to my coffeescript. 
The Jquery equivalent would be

```
$(".pickthetime").on('dp.show', function(){
  $(document).find('.picker-switch a[data-action="togglePicker"]').click()
});
```

It sort of does what I'm looking for, but the slide motion makes it look kinda crappy. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents

```
('#myDatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        icons: {
            time: "icona-orologio",
        }
    }).on('dp.show', function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').find('.icona-orologio').parent().click();
        }, 300);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're rarely changing the date, maybe using a timepicker would be more suited to your project.  You could have a separate picker for each as well.

[Bootstrap Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

I found:

[Bootstrap Datepicker docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

> Defaults for all options can be modified directly by changing values in the $.fn.datepicker.defaults hash:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     startDate: '-3d'
})
```

Change the format string to:

```
"HH:MM:SS mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: It still can happen enough, that I'd probably stick to the dual selection. I've updated the post, but what I had originally meant was the datetimepicker defaulting to the clock screen first as opposed to the calendar screen. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [format options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) that you can use for the plugin.
For time first use this as format : 'HH:mm:ss a MM/DD/YYYY' this will translate to '21:55:30 pm 07/19/2015'

Check all the available options for the plugin [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format)

Comment: Sorry I realize now that I wasn't very clear, and I've updated the post, I meant the edit time screen. Right now the plug-in defaults to the calendar view first, and that is what i'd like to change. Thanks for your help!